# how to save the date as static value when Y is placed in J12

Tags: excel

i am using the below formula in google sheet with enabling iterative calculations on in spreadsheet settings. every work has specified date to done on. and each date has 3 columns (please see row 9 & 10)."P" (planned date which comes by column E), "A"(actual date which comes by whenever we fill "Y" by drop down in adjacent column , "Y" (whenever any task get completed it may be on same day or later).

=If(J12="Y",if(I12="",NOW(),I12),"")

i was using today formula for last two years without any problem. the dates were not changing at all. but in my new file it starts to get change. so i was trying with now function. but this is also getting changed.

so i want to have a fix that whenever we fill y for any particular date the dates in "A" columns should not be changed. i don't know anything about scripts. so if it needs script please tell me how to execute and how to apply in each sheet too.

this is my first question on stack overflow. hoping to get this as solved. here is the link of the file.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EKIf5HPYEjyd94B-HsmEh-bFor-9vRQmuTIxka9_HZI/edit#gid=1924994592

Comment: I think this is not a question someone will answer here. There is no out of the box script what can do this for you. You need to hire a scripter.